# Why does this virtual destructor does not work in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

I'm trying to delete an object of a subclass. Although I used a virtual destructor, I am still getting the error message:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee08bab50: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
  protected:
    int age;
  public:
    Animal(){
      age = 0;
      cout << "ctor Animal" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Animal(){
      cout << "dtor Animal" << endl;
    }
};

class Mammal : public Animal{
  public:
    Mammal(){
      age = 0;
      cout << "ctor Mammal" << endl;
    }
    ~Mammal(){
    cout << "dtor Mammal" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
  Mammal *dog = new Mammal();
  delete &dog;
}
```

I would be very thankful, if someone helped me!

Comment: You should `delete dog;`.

Comment: Voted to close as simple typo.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49465726/edit) to include more information if commenters ask.  Don't worry if your question does get closed - it's nothing personal :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@songyuanyao is right: `delete dog` instead of `delete &dog`.  You have allocated memory whose address is stored in `dog`.  `&dog` is the address of *where that address is stored*, probably on the stack.  So `&dog` is a `Mammal **` that you did not `new`, but that was instead created automatically by the compiler on the stack.  Since you didn't `new` it, you can't `delete` it.

By the way, if you want to see the effect of the virtual destructor, use `Animal *dog = new Mammal();`.  Since you are declaring `dog` as a `Mammal` and creating it as a `Mammal`, the correct destructor would be called regardless of whether or not it were virtual.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You allocated a `Mammal*` then deleted a `Mammal**` that pointed at the stack.  Deleting things on the stack is not allowed.

```
delete dog;
```

is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! :)